# New chestnut project: Editing app-state doesn't refresh browser

Tags: clojurescript, om

After getting hyped by Nolen's great talks, I decided to give Clojurescript and Om a go.

Everything works as advertised - except I'm a bit surprised that editing the `app-state` doesn't refresh the browser like editing `style.css` or the Om component tree does.

I'm guessing this is intentional and that there's a good reason why editing `app-state` doesn't refresh the browser. However, I'm very new to ClojureScript and don't quite know where yet to go digging for the answer.

Any help/insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, 5 minutes after I post this question, I run across the answer.

Taken from Om's [Basic Tutorial](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial):

> The reason we need to refresh the browser is because app-state is defined with defonce. This is meant to prevent each reload from resetting the state.